# Android Studio have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

```
Process: com.example.test1, PID: 21971
```

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test1/com.example.test1.Activities.GroupChatActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

```
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5314)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:712)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5272)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:693)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5658)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5611)

at com.example.test1.Activities.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:235)


at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4269)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ComponentActivity.java:514)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:352)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:266)
at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:110)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1189)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:836)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:159)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:987)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1187)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3179)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4097)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

and this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="match_parent"android:background="@drawable/bg"tools:context=".Activities.GroupChatActivity">
```

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sentBtn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/attachment"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:tint="#676767"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attachment" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:tint="#676767"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sentBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send" />
```

```
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is Activiti

```
package com.example.test1.Activities;
```

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;import android.os.Bundle;import android.view.View;
```

```
import com.example.test1.Adapters.MessagesAdapter;import com.example.test1.Models.Message;import com.example.test1.R;import com.example.test1.databinding.ActivityGroupChatBinding;import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;import java.util.Date;
```

```
public class GroupChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

```
com.example.test1.databinding.ActivityGroupChatBinding binding;
MessagesAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Message> messages;

FirebaseDatabase database;
FirebaseStorage storage;

ProgressDialog dialog;

String senderUid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = com.example.test1.databinding.ActivityGroupChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Group Chat");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Uploading image...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    messages = new ArrayList<>();

    binding.sentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String messageTxt = binding.messageBox.getText().toString();

            Date date = new Date();
            Message message = new Message(messageTxt, senderUid, date.getTime());
            binding.messageBox.setText("");

            database.getReference().child("public")
                    .push()
                    .setValue(message);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}

and tihi is MainActiviti

```
package com.example.test1.Activities;
```

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;import androidx.annotation.Nullable;import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;import android.content.Intent;import android.net.Uri;import android.os.Bundle;import android.view.Menu;import android.view.MenuItem;import android.widget.Toast;
```

```
import com.example.test1.Adapters.TopStatusAdapter;import com.example.test1.Models.Status;import com.example.test1.Models.UserStatus;import com.example.test1.R;import com.example.test1.Models.User;import com.example.test1.Adapters.UsersAdapter;import com.example.test1.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;import java.util.Date;import java.util.HashMap;
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

```
ActivityMainBinding binding;
FirebaseDatabase database;
ArrayList<User> users;
UsersAdapter usersAdapter;
TopStatusAdapter statusAdapter;
ArrayList<UserStatus> userStatuses;
ProgressDialog dialog;

User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    dialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users = new ArrayList<>();
    userStatuses = new ArrayList<>();

    database.getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(this, users);
    statusAdapter = new TopStatusAdapter(this, userStatuses);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
binding.statusList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
binding.statusList.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

    binding.recyclerView.showShimmerAdapter();
    binding.statusList.showShimmerAdapter();

    database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            users.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                if (!user.getUid().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()))
                     users.add(user);
            }
            binding.recyclerView.hideShimmerAdapter();
            usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    database.getReference().child("stories").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                userStatuses.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot storySnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    UserStatus status = new UserStatus();
                    status.setName(storySnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
                    status.setProfileImage(storySnapshot.child("profileImage").getValue(String.class));
                    status.setLastUpdated(storySnapshot.child("lastUpdated").getValue(Long.class));

                    ArrayList<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot statusSnapshot :  storySnapshot.child("statuses").getChildren()) {
                        Status sampleStatus = statusSnapshot.getValue(Status.class);
                        statuses.add(sampleStatus);
                    }

                    status.setStatuses(statuses);
                    userStatuses.add(status);
                }
                binding.statusList.hideShimmerAdapter();
                statusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.status:
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 75);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        if (data.getData() != null) {
            dialog.show();
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            Date date = new Date();
            StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("status").child(date.getTime() + "" );


            reference.putFile(data.getData()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                UserStatus userStatus = new UserStatus();
                                userStatus.setName(user.getName());
                                userStatus.setProfileImage(user.getProfileImage());
                                userStatus.setLastUpdated(date.getTime());

                                HashMap<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<>();
                                obj.put("name", userStatus.getName());
                                obj.put("profileImage", userStatus.getProfileImage());
                                obj.put("lastUpdated", userStatus.getLastUpdated());

                                String imageUrl = uri.toString();
                                Status status = new Status(imageUrl, userStatus.getLastUpdated());

                                database.getReference()
                                        .child("stories")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                        .updateChildren(obj);

                                database.getReference().child("stories")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                        .child("statuses")
                                        .push()
                                        .setValue(status);

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String currentId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    database.getReference().child("presence").child(currentId).setValue("Online");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    String currentId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    database.getReference().child("presence").child(currentId).setValue("Offline");
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.group:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GroupChatActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.search:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Search Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.topmenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

}
```

and this is AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Test1"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".GroupChatActivity"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ChatActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test1.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SetupProfileActivity"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.OTPActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.PhoneNumberActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Problem this is here when i pres eror Locgcat MainActivity

> ```
> startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GroupChatActivity.class));
> ```

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.group:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GroupChatActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.search:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Search Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

```
<activity
        android:name=".GroupChatActivity"
        android:exported="ture">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: package name should be in lower case only by [convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html). Your `.GroupChatActivity` in manifest should be `.Activities.GroupChatActivity` like others ..

Answer (score 0):

Your `GroupChatActivity` is in the package `com.example.test1.Activities` but the manifest entry for `GroupChatActivity` has a different package ´com.example.test1`- looks like you're missing`.Activities` in the manifest entry.